# Determine filter type using recurrence relation

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, z-transform, transfer-function, highpass-filter

Given the recurrence relation:
$y[n] = x[n] + 0.5y[n-1]$
I want to determine the filter type (i.e. LPF, HPF etc.)

I try to use Z transform, and get that the the transfer function is
$H(z) = \frac{2z}{2z-1}$
So I derive that the filter is HPF (High pass). Is it correct?

Comment: Hint : what is the gain at z = 1? I.e. DC. Is it 0? If it's not 0, it's not a high-pass filter.

Comment: H(1) = 2 and H(infinity) = 1, so it means it is LPF?

Comment: Evaluating at z = infinity makes no sense. The frequency response is evaluated over the unit circle, with DC at z = 1, and freq pi at z = -1

Comment: So how I determine the type of the filter?

Comment: Most filters don't fit an easy category like high/low pass. Why do you need to know the filter type and what is the range of "allowed" answers ?